# Gson - how to special processing like masking

Tags: java, gson

How to configure Gson to do additional processing on the value for toJson?

```
public class MyClass{
    @SerializedName("qwerty")
    @Mask(exposeFront=2, exposeRear=2, mask="*")
    private String qwerty
}
```

Assuming `MyClass#qwerty` has a value of `1234567890`, how to set Gson to output `{"qwerty":"12******90"}`?

Answer (score 1):

Gson `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory`, that is responsible for "plain" objects serialization and deserialization, is not possible to enhance to support any other annotations like `@Masked`. It can only use annotations like `@Expose` (indirectly via an exclusion strategy), `@SerializedName` and a few others like `@Since` and `@Until` (exclusion strategy too). Note these annotations are documented and supported by default. In general, Gson suggests using a type adapter for the declaring class, `MyClass`, but this also means that you must manage **all** fields and make sure the corresponding type adapter is updated once your class is changed. Even worse, adding a custom type adapter makes these annotations support lost.

As an another way of working around it is injecting a special string type adapter factory that can do the trick, but due to the mechanics of how it is injected, this is both limited and requires duplicating the `@Masked` annotation values (if you're using the annotation elsewhere in your code) and the type adapter factory configuration in `@JsonAdapter`.

```java
public abstract class MaskedTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private final int exposeFront;
    private final int exposeRear;
    private final char mask;

    private MaskedTypeAdapterFactory(final int exposeFront, final int exposeRear, final char mask) {
        this.exposeFront = exposeFront;
        this.exposeRear = exposeRear;
        this.mask = mask;
    }

    // must be "baked" into the class (name only represents the configuration)
    public static final class _2_2_asterisk
            extends MaskedTypeAdapterFactory {

        private _2_2_asterisk() {
            super(2, 2, '*');
        }

    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( typeToken.getRawType() != String.class ) {
            return null;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<String> delegate = (TypeAdapter<String>) gson.getAdapter(typeToken);
        final TypeAdapter<String> typeAdapter = new TypeAdapter<String>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final String value)
                    throws IOException {
                // mask the value
                final int length = value.length();
                final char[] buffer = value.toCharArray();
                for ( int i = exposeFront; i < length - exposeRear; i++ ) {
                    buffer[i] = mask;
                }
                out.value(new String(buffer));
            }

            @Override
            public String read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                return delegate.read(in);
            }
        }
                .nullSafe();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> adapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) typeAdapter;
        return adapter;
    }

}
```

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
final class MyClass {

    @SerializedName("qwerty")
    @Mask(exposeFront = 2, exposeRear = 2, mask = "*")
    // unfortunately, this must duplicate the @Mask annotation values
    // since type adapter (factories) do not accept supplemental information
    // and Java annotations can only accept compile-time constants
    @JsonAdapter(MaskedTypeAdapterFactory._2_2_asterisk.class)
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String qwerty;

}
```

Test:

```java
public final class MaskedTypeAdapterFactoryTest {

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .disableInnerClassSerialization()
            .create();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final String actual = gson.toJson(new MyClass("1234567890"));
        final String expected = "{\"qwerty\":\"12******90\"}";
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

This is probably the most robust way of doing that in Gson.